# Unable to retrieve textbox text using selenium in grails application

Tags: javascript, selenium, grails, ecmascript-6

I am currently trying to make automated tests for a grails application for my company.  I am using selenium in javascript.  The problem is that I need to check whether a form is generated with values in it but whenever I try to check the value, it gives me a long error.  Here is the code that is supposed to work:

```
console.log(
    driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[@id='manual-order-mail-from-name']")
    ).getAttribute("value")
);
```

The element that I am trying to get is here:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control input-sm mail-from-input valid" 
    name="mailFromName" 
    id="manual-order-mail-from-name" 
    placeholder="Name" 
    required="" 
    aria-required="true" 
    aria-invalid="false">
```

And here is the error message:

```
ManagedPromise {
  flow_: 
   ControlFlow {
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_: 
      TaskQueue {
        name_: 'TaskQueue::709',
        flow_: [Circular],
        tasks_: [Object],
        interrupts_: null,
        pending_: null,
        subQ_: null,
        state_: 'new',
        unhandledRejections_: Set {} },
     taskQueues_: Set { [Object] },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     hold_: 
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 461,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 2147483647 } },
  stack_: 
   { Task: WebElement.getAttribute(value)
       at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
       at WebElementPromise.schedule_ (/Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1921:25)
       at WebElementPromise.getAttribute (/Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2171:17)
       at /Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/TEST-11.js:43:92
       at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1384:14)
       at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3092:14)
       at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3075:27)
       at asyncRun (/Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2935:27)
       at /Users/takeshi/WebstormProjects/Regression/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7) name: 'Task' },
  parent_: null,
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  value_: undefined,
  queue_: null }
```

It's part of a modal that appears when the user clicks on a button.  My guess is that this has something to do with it but I have no clue.

I've searched all over and can't seem to find a solution.  If you have any insight on this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had an incorrect understanding of what getAttribute returned.  It actually returns a promise that you then need to catch and then output.  Like so:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='manual-order-mail-from-name']")).getAttribute("value").then(function (success) {console.log("this is the text" + success);}, function(e) {console.log("this was the error" + e);});`